# Android ListView scrolls the entire screen

Tags: android, list, listview, scroll, scrollable

I have created a layout containing many linear layouts, and I have, in one of the linear layouts, 3 ListViews set side by side. I want to make each one of them scrollable, but singularily. For example, I want to be able to scroll one of them without anything else being affected.

Right now, if I set "android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"" for any one of the lists, the entire screen scrolls. I want the scrolling of the list to be confined to the layout the list is in (so I can scroll the list and the rest of the screen stays in place).

How can I do that? So far, it's either no scrolling at all, or scrolling the entire screen. I just want the list to scroll.

Thanks!

PS: Here's how the relevant part of the XML looks like (nothing special about it):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/list_vertical_margin">

       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/realtime_vehicle_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/realtime_errors_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/realtime_depot_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your XML file here .............

Comment: Well, it's a big one, I'm not sure if I have enough characters to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. Apparently, the layout "continues" beyond the screen. I only put a few more elements to test if it scrolls, but in reality, the reason why only the 3rd list was scrolling and the other two weren't is because the 3rd list had more elements, and it went beyond its limits. That's why it was scrolling.

I was equating the "going out of the screen" with the idea that the list should scroll, but it's just a design problem - the operating system didn't think that the list was going off the screen.

As soon as I put more elements into the other two lists, they are now all scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

One of your `LinearLayout`s is in a `ScrollView`, I guess. So remove the ScrollView.

Comment: No. Checked, double checked and triple checked, just to be sure. I've only used LinearLayouts

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the next following code in the activity that contains those Listviews:

```
ListView mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
mylistview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't do anything. However, weirdly enough, now one of the lists does indeed scroll. But I've removed your code and it still scrolls :))

So, I now have three lists one next to the other, but only the 3rd one scrolls. All three of them are in one LinearLayout with horizontal orientation.

Comment: I have an activity in one of my projects similar that you are describing, I had a similar issue like you. I have in my code the lines I posted you but I don't have this in my xml: android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" try to erased it put the code I gave you and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah I've used that before and it just scrolled the entire screen. What's weird about all this is that the 3rd list, the last one in the LinearLayout, does indeed scroll. I tried to put them each in their own separate LinearLayouts, thinking that maybe they want to be "alone in their own layout" for them to scroll individually, but it's still the 3rd list that scrolls. The other 2 don't scroll. This makes no sense. Obviously there's something "special" about the 3rd one and I'm trying to find out what that is.

Comment: I've figured it out, check out my response above.

Comment: Would be interesting if you can post the XML of your activity that contains the listviews.

Comment: I have edited my original message to display the relevant code, for you :P

But it's nothing special about it. The issue was the fact that "it didn't go off the screen enough" to make the Android Operating System to give the lists the ability to scroll. As soon as I added more elements, that started to become obvious (the lists were suddenly scrolling). Then I adjusted the margins (even though it looked terrible in the preview, in Android Studio) - when running it on the tablet it worked. Granted, I'm using hardcoded values which is terrible, but...